# Objective-C add an NSButton to my iphone app at runtime

Tags: objective-c, button, runtime, addition

I am absolutely clueless on this front! Step-by-step explanation earns bonus points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In iOS We have UIButtons (not NSButtons)

Here is how to create an UIButton programmatically:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; //3
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, 100,100 )];
[button setTitle:@"PressMe!" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];//2
[aView addSubview:button]; //1
```

and :

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender{

    //do something here ;)
    [sender setTitle:@"PressMe!. Again" forState:UIControlStateNormal];


}
```

**1**: if you are in a `UIViewController`, then `aView` will be `self.view`
if you are somewhere else, just pass the view that will contain your button

**2**: the easiest case is like that but you can set any object as a target. That object must have to have the method you pass in the `@selector(...)`. Otherwise you app will crash when pressing the button.

Comment: Allright, most of your code makes sense, but I am a little confused on the aView part. I have a custom controller class which is a subclass of NSObject. This contains a response to an "add button" button. I'm confused as to how to get the proper view. What are the most common ways of doing this?

Comment: does your custom controller have or controls a view? Do you have a reference to something like UIView *view os something like that?  try passing that. As I said aView will be the view (something that inherits from UIView) that contains your button.

Comment: In interface builder when you create you button you always put in on another view right? that view is the view I am talking about ;) You program should be a similar case but programmatically

Comment: I am seriously new to this. I have no clue how to acquire that view in code. :P

Comment: Ages later... I finally figure out how to get the view. Works like a charm! :) Sorry for the delay in answer-aproval

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure of all the steps to do that in code, but what I would do is use the interface builder to create the button where you want it.  Then when you load the view, make the button hidden in the viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear method.  Make the button visible when you need to.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thankyou for the tip. :) Unfortunately that won't work for me. I will potentially be adding any number of buttons to the system. Must be done 100% runtime.